# Pandas: concatenate strings in column based on a flag in another column until flag changes

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to concatenate strings in a column based on the values in another column.  While this inherently isn't difficult, here the order of the flags matter so I can't think of a pythonic method to accomplish this task (currently trying multiple counters/loops).

Example table:

```
text    flag
a       0
b       0
c       1
d       0
e       1
f       1
g       1
```

Example output:

```
text    flag
ab      0
c       1
d       0
efg     1
```

I want to `''.join` every string for consecutive flags until the next flag is hit.  The only flags are 1 and 0.  Any ideas?

Here's a quick way to generate the example data so you don't have to do it yourself:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'], 'flag':[0,0,1,0,1,1,1]})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
In [6]: (df.groupby(df.flag.diff().ne(0).cumsum(), as_index=False)
           .agg({'text':'sum','flag':'first'}))
Out[6]:
  text  flag
0   ab     0
1    c     1
2    d     0
3  efg     1
```